# How do I configure rsyslog mmfields to split an oddly formatted syslog message from an outgoing TACACS server?

Tags: rsyslog

I have a valid Rsyslog configuration which generally is working well.
RSyslog version 8.2102.0-10.el8

However I am receiving an oddly formatted (and rather obsolete) "syslog" message from an End of Live TACACS server that is due to be replaced.
Basically I am trying to re-write the tacacs message such that I can remove a lot of irrelevant information in the data stream, leaving the crucial parts and therefore reducing the size of the syslog files.

The format of the message sent to the syslog server is similar to the following:

```
2023-03-15T10:10:57+00:00 SERVER1 CSCOacs_Passed_Authentications 0887851664 1 0 2023-03-15 10:10:57.267 +00:00 0424495644 5201 NOTICE Passed-Authentication: Authentication succeeded, ACSVersion=acs-5.5.0.46-B.723, ConfigVersionId=33, Device IP Address=10.5.1.2, DestinationIPAddress=10.4.2.1, DestinationPort=49, UserName=testapi, Protocol=Tacacs, RequestLatency=4, Type=Authentication, Action=Login, Privilege-Level=0, Authen-Type=ASCII, Service=Login, User=testapi, Port=eth0, Remote-Address=10.2.2.1, UserName=testapi, AcsSessionID=SERVER1/462353176/34805778, AuthenticationIdentityStore=Internal Users, AuthenticationMethod=PAP_ASCII, SelectedAccessService=Local User Db TACACS, SelectedShellProfile=Admin_Role, IdentityGroup=IdentityGroup:All Groups:Accounts, Step=13013 , Step=15008 , Step=15004 , Step=15012 , Step=15041 , Step=15006 , Step=15013 , Step=24210 , Step=24212 , Step=13045 , Step=13015 , Step=13014 , Step=15037 , Step=15041 , Step=15006 , Step=15013 , Step=24210 , Step=24212 , Step=22037 , Step=15044 , Step=15035 , Step=15042 , Step=15036 , Step=15004 , Step=13015 , SelectedAuthenticationIdentityStores=Internal Users, SelectedAuthenticationIdentityStores=Internal Users, NetworkDeviceName=Cisco, NetworkDeviceGroups=Device Type:All Device Types:Cisco, NetworkDeviceGroups=Location:All Locations:All_Locations, ServiceSelectionMatchedRule=Local_Users_TACACS, IdentityPolicyMatchedRule=Default, AuthorizationPolicyMatchedRule=Rule_1, Action=Login, Privilege-Level=0, Authen-Type=ASCII, Service=Login, Port=eth0, Remote-Address=10.2.2.1, UserIdentityGroup=IdentityGroup:All Groups:Accounts, Response={Type=Authentication; Authen-Reply-Status=Pass; }
```

So I am using:

```
module(load="mmfields")
template(name="parsed" type="list"){
    property(name="timestamp")
    constant(value=",")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value=",")
    property(name="syslogtag")
    constant(value=",")
    constant(value="\n")
}
if ($fromhost-ip contains "10.1.2.3") then {

        action(type="mmfields"
                separator=","
        )
        action( type     = "omfile"
                file     = "/rsyslogdata/tacacs/parsed.log"
                template = "parsed"
        )

}
```

The end result is that I get the following output:

```
May 30 21:22:57,SERVER1,CSCOacs_Passed_Authentications,
May 30 21:22:57,SERVER1,CSCOacs_Passed_Authentications,
May 30 21:22:58,SERVER1,CSCOacs_Passed_Authentications,
```

where the timestamp is "May 30 21:22:57",
syslogtag is "CSCOacs_Passed_Authentications"
hostname is "SERVER1".
(information anonymised)

I assumed that using the default separator (,) the msg part would be split as well but this isnt what is happening.
There is no field "$!f4" or anything.
The only thing I get is the entire msg in one field which is not what i want. I was expecting the msg to be split into individual fields (e.g. $!f5, $!f6 etc) as well but that is not what is happening.

Comment: What exactly is the *"crucial parts"* of the message? Also I can't see any part of the message included in your example result (and neither in your config) - so what do you mean by *"the message is not split"*?

Comment: @eDonkey. Thanks for the reply & Point taken about what I am trying to extract. One issue that I found after posting the question (and I tried to add as my response) was that mmfields was not installed and so I was going to get the server team to do this.This has now been done but I have not had chance to revisit this.  
Basically the 3 that main ones are Timestamp, Hostname, syslogtag.
Then after that, I need to split the msg, using commas as the delimeter.
In the msg, I want to extract the fields Device IP Address, UserName, Remote-Address and Response. The remainder is not needed.